# "invalid arithmetic operator" error when trying to add variables in Bash script

Tags: bash, scripts

Coming from a Python background, this is my first simple Bash script and it does not work. I'm confused.

```
#!/bin/bash
RTCHOST='192.168.0.143'
PANEL1=$(client read-value --host $RTCHOST --name dc_1)
echo Panel1: $PANEL1
PANEL2=$(client read-value --host $RTCHOST --name dc_2)
echo Panel2: $PANEL2
PANELCONSUMPTION=$(($PANEL1 + $PANEL2))
echo Consumption: $PANELCONSUMPTION
```

When I run the script, I get a syntax error:

```
invalid arithmetic operator
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess `$PANEL1` and `$PANEL2` are floating point numbers. However, Bash is only capable of handling integers, not floating point numbers, as explained in [Arithmetic Expansion](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html). If you try to sum floating point numbers, you will get the `invalid arithmetic operator` error.

Simply try it here:

```
#!/bin/bash
A='5'
B='6.4'
C=$(($A + $B))
echo $C
```

Adding floating point numbers is described in this Stack Overflow thread: [How can I add numbers in a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348902/how-can-i-add-numbers-in-a-bash-script)

In essence, you can use an external utility, such as `bc`, to do the operation as shown in this example:

```
#!/bin/bash
A='5'
B='6.4'
C=$(echo $A + $B | bc) 
echo $C
```

This works and returns the expected value of 11.4.

Comment: `echo $A + $B` should probably be `echo "$A + $B"` for good measure; no reason to do unquoted expansion of those variables.  Unless you need to eat newlines that might mess up `bc`, if they came from capturing `$(command substitution)`.